# echo the date, one week from the current date

Tags: php, date, datetime

Assume today is wed, first of may, 2014.  I want to get date of last week Mon.

```
$CurrentDay = date(l);
if ($CurrentDay == "Monday" AND $CurrentDay != "Wednesday" ) { 
   $AdjustedDate = date(j)-3; 
   $SetDate = $AdjustedDate."/".date(m)."/".date(Y);  
}
```

It all goes well till the date is like "1" or something like that the value is "-".

Comment: You want the date of the past monday? In your example? You want 29 april? Or 1 more week exta?

Comment: Don’t try to calculate the day yourself, use `strtotime` instead.

Comment: @CBroe ok,how can you convert that back to the date integer?

Comment: Using `date`, as you would with any other timestamp …

Comment: @X10nD If you take todays date, what you want as output? 5May or 28 april?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to minus your days with current date

```
echo $CurrentDay = date(l); //Friday
if($CurrentDay) { 
echo $AdjustedDate = date('d/m/Y l', strtotime('last Week Monday', strtotime($CurrentDay)));     
//28/04/2014 Monday
```

Comment: @X10nD last week monday check now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate past monday, use this:

```
$timestamp = time();
$monday = idate('w', $timestamp) == 1 ? $timestamp : strtotime("last Monday", $timestamp);
```

Now you got the Timestamp of the monday, and you can just do:

```
echo date("d/m/Y", $monday);
```